# AnkhSVN for Subversion does not show Source-Code-Control related icons

Tags: c#, svn, visual-studio-2005, icons, ankhsvn

We moved our projects (SQL Server and .Net) from Visual-Source-Safe to SubVersion.

We have installed Tortoise SVN and AnkhSVN clients on the location machine.

When I lock a file, the icon in Windows Explorer changes, but there is no indication in Visual Studio of any lock.

Visual-Studio

[image]

Windows Explorer

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you happen to be on 64-bit Windows? (If in doubt, do a `winver` to find out)

Comment: Please provide Visual Studio version as well.

Comment: I am on Windows XP 32-bit SP3

Comment: How did you create this paper tear effect?

Comment: Using a screen capture tool called Snagit. http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

I had added the Solution to SVN but not added the projects to SVN.

Funnily enough, when you add a Solution to SVN, it adds all the files to SVN, but it does not modify the project to manage them via SVN as well - this is a step you have to do manually.

Then the icons show up!

Comment: The most common (modern) project types somehow don't require that you take this step even though Microsoft recommends that you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have AnkhSVN as your currently selected source control plugin.

Tools -> Options -> Source Control.

Comment: confirmed - AnkhSVN is my Source Control Plugin

Answer (score 0):

add **svn:needs-lock** property in locked file to let AnkhSVN show file locked in Visual Studio, see:
http://ankhsvntips.net/post/2378796136/auto-locking-files